# NSOutlineView MoveItemAtIndex Doesn't Animate

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I have a (view-based) NSOUtlineView that is programatically fully functional with drag and drop - i.e. I've implemented all of the correct methods and everything seems to work fine. Everything, that is, except animations.

When I execute MoveItemAtIndex, the row movements do not animate. The row is moved however, because when I scroll up or down the view refreshes and the row is in its new place. I've confirmed that all of the input arguments are correct.

Furthermore, when I send an invalid "oldParent" item, the row insertion animation works correctly! And if I send an invalid "newParent" item, the row removal animation works correctly! Needless to say, this confuses me - am I missing something regarding the function of MoveItemAtIndex? There seem to precious little in the docs, everything seems to indicate that the animation should "just work".

I've tried with and without the beginUpdates/endUpdates, getting the same result each time.

To anyone's knowledge, is there something that is not documented or hard to find regarding these animations?

Thanks

Comment: Same problem. Did you turn out to find the solution?

Comment: Nope, sorry, never did! Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I got caught with something similar with collection views. Try...

```
outlineView.animator().moveItem(...
```